# How to save in php var an Javascript output

Tags: javascript, php, variables, curl, ob-start

I have an cURL php output in a variable that contains the following code

```
document.writeln('<tr>')
document.writeln('<td align=left valign=top> SOME TEXT </td>')
document.writeln('<td class=tdrescent valign=top>10-04-2013</td>')
document.writeln('<td class=tdrescent valign=top>10-04</td>')
document.writeln('<td class=tdresizq valign=top> TEXT</td>')
document.writeln('</tr>')
```

i need to extract the content of the table.( some text ,10-04-2013,10-04,TEXT)

I try it to  save it in a variable, making an ob_start() to capture the output but don't work.

```
  ob_start();
  echo $out;
  $html = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
```

i try it this to save an html content in a variable an after that, work with this.

what can i do ?

Comment: Off-topic: [Don't use `document.write`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29), use `innerHTML` or DOM methods instead. And DOM interactions are expensive, so first concatenate your strings in order to reduce them.

Comment: I can't change this because its a string that i recieve from a server, i can't change the document.write.